# How do I type an object with multiple child objects that have enum type keys?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript I have an object like this:

```
enum MyEnum {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B',
  C = 'C',
};

type MyData = {
  name: string,
  description: string,
};

const obj = {
  [MyEnum.A]: {
    name: 'one',
    description: 'two',
  } as MyData,
  [MyEnum.B]: {
    name: 'three',
    description: 'four',
  } as MyData,
  // ... etc ... many entries ..
};

console.log( 'value: ', obj[MyEnum.A] );
```

How do I create a type when the object acts like an array?

```
const obj: ??? = {
  // ...
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures). If every member of MyEnum is required to have an entry in the object, this will look like:

```
const obj: { [key in MyEnum]: MyData } = {
  [MyEnum.A]: {
    title: 'one',
    description: 'two',
  },
  [MyEnum.B]: {
    title: 'three',
    description: 'four',
  },
  // ... etc
}
```

If only *some* of MyEnum are present, then you can make it optional:

```
{ [key in MyEnum]?: MyData }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gWAFBSgQSgXigHIciAaTbAIQOKvMqgGFaimGMBfAbk0wBc4AB2Cw4AEQCG-SbXRYo-AJb8ANsABcUAM78ATkpABzCgoAmwbQGMDQ5QHsQW3QeOmefDFce6o9gEYAVlooUADaANbAcFCGYkiQALpa8FIyUJxyjGHwCRAAdDjJUPLY2MpqmsSOwBxlUBbWtg5OxPwA7vZ1GabYOYjI%20VTFpWUV6lpE-AAWesC1vWWNNkp2So6TAGb2YHrdnIv9eflMI4zlKhPEm0oAbgvnDZYraxvE2koAHvvuQA)